# How to index parent and child documents using java API in Elasticsearch version 6.2.1

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am not able to retrieve the parent/child documents from ES based on my implementation below.

STEP 1: Relation

```
{
  "versionjoin": {
    "properties": {
      "my_join_field": {
        "type": "join",
        "relations": {
          "version": "accountversion"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

STEP 2: This is how I am indexing parent document.

```
{
    String pattern = YYYY_MM_DD_HH_MM_SS;
                            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
                            String date = simpleDateFormat.format(index_timestamp);
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                            JSONObject joinObject = new JSONObject();
                            obj.put(VERSIONNUMBER, versionNumber);
                            obj.put(VERSIONDATE, date);
                            obj.put("my_join_field","version");

                                            client.prepareIndex(
                                                    versionIndexName,
                                                    versionJoinType)
                                                    .setId(versionNumber)
                                                    .setSource(obj.toString(),XContentType.JSON)
                                                    .execute()
                                                    .actionGet();
                                    }
```

STEP 3: This is how I am trying to index the child document.

```
JsonNode node = serializeMapper.readTree(json);
ObjectNode addedNode = ((ObjectNode) node).putObject("my_join_field");
addedNode
        .put("name", "accountversion")
        .put("parent", association.getVersion());
String modifiedJson = serializeMapper.writeValueAsString(addedNode);

indexResponse = client.prepareIndex(versionIndexName, versionJoinType)
                        .setId(String.valueOf(association.getId() + ":" +
                                                association.getVersion()))
                        .setRouting(association.getVersion())
                        .setSource(modifiedJson,XContentType.JSON).get();
```

When I try to retrieve the documents using document Id and routing I don't see any documents in the result. I recently migrated the ES from 2.4 to 6.2 and I changed the above implementation to read parent and child documents from the same index. As the type support has been deprecated in ES 6.2. Can anyone suggest if i am doing anything in an incorrect way.

Answer (score 0):

The parent and the childs must be stored on the same shards, so ensure that the call `setRouting` is using the same routing of the parent.

Comment: I am setting the routing on child document as the same routing of parent.